# Drag and drop whole frame and update dict

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a GUI example written in tkinter. Firstly, it reads a dictionary and organaizes the key/value pairs into a table composed of labels.
Each value also corresponding "open" ans "detail" widgets.
What I want to do now is to make the `value_label` vertically draggable, and update the "read_dict" based on the dragging result. the corresponding "open" ans "detail" widgets can also be updated along with the `value_label`.

This is an example without the drag-and-drop functionality added yet.
Can someone help for this? It has been bothering e for a very long time!!

```
import tkinter as tk
import yaml
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

win_root = Tk()
win_root.title("Read dict")

cv = None
scrollbar = None

def update_scrollregion(event):
    cv.configure(scrollregion = cv.bbox('all'))

def open_file(value):
    print(f"open {value} !!")

def detail_frame_show(detail_text ,detail_frame):
    global frame_name
    if frame_name != "":
        frame_name.grid_remove()
    detail_frame.grid()
    detail_text.grid()
    frame_name = detail_frame

def create_title(event):
    global cv
    global scrollbar
    global frame_name
    
    if cv:
        cv.destroy()
    if scrollbar:
        scrollbar.destroy()
    scrollbar = Scrollbar(win_root,orient='vertical')
    cv = tk.Canvas(win_root, scrollregion=(0,0,400,400), yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, height = 300)
    scrollbar.config(command=cv.yview)
    scrollbar.pack(side='right',fill='y')

    read_dict={'KEYAA':[{'valueaa':None, 'source':'local'},{'valuejj':None},{'valuecc':None}],'KEYF':[{'valuea':None, 'exist':'None'},{'valuej':None},{'value':None}],'KEYE':[{'valuez':None, 'check':'no'},{'valueeeee':None},{'valuecde':None}]}

    key_list = list(read_dict.keys())
    frame2 = tk.Frame(cv)
    frame2.bind('<Configure>', update_scrollregion)
    frame2_window = cv.create_window((0,0), window=frame2, anchor='nw')
    row_num = 1
    for key in key_list:
        value_list = read_dict[key]
        key_label = key + "_label"
        key_label=ttk.Label(frame2,text=key,anchor='center',relief='sunken', width =15, background='gray')
        key_label.grid(row= row_num, column = 0 ,sticky='news',columnspan=3)
        row_num += 1
        for value_dict in value_list:
            for value in value_dict:
                key_value = str(key) + str(value)
                value_label = key_value + "_label"
                value_label =ttk.Label(frame2,text=value,anchor='center',relief='sunken',width=30)
                open_button = key_value + "_open_button"
                open_button = tk.Button(frame2, text="OPEN",width=11, command=lambda value = value:open_file(value))
                value_label.grid(row=row_num,column=0, sticky='news')
                open_button.grid(row=row_num,column=1, sticky='news')
                row_num += 1
                detail_frame = key_value + "_detail_frame"
                detail_frame = tk.Frame(frame2,bg='white', width =70)
                detail_frame.grid(row=row_num,column=0, sticky='news',columnspan=3)
                option_text = tk.StringVar()
                option = value_dict[value]
                if not option:
                    option = ""
                option = yaml.dump(option)
                option_text.set(option)
                detail_text = key_value + "_detail_text"
                detail_text = tk.Text(detail_frame)
                detail_text.insert('1.0',option)
                detail_text.grid(row=row_num, sticky='news', columnspan=4)
                detail_text.grid_remove()
                frame_name = ""
                value_label.bind('<Enter>',lambda event, detail_text = detail_text, detail_frame=detail_frame: detail_frame_show(detail_text ,detail_frame))
                row_num += 1
    cv.pack(side='top',fill='both',expand='true')

create_title(event=None)
#Display the main window
win_root.mainloop()
```

According to the above code, it will first generate the title `KEYAA` and then generate labels for values like "valueaa" and so on.
If I drag the label `valueaa` down below the label `valuecc`.
Please update the read_dict to

```
{'KEYAA':{'valuejj':None},{'valuecc':None},[{'valueaa':None, 'source':'local'}],'KEYF':[{'valuea':None, 'exist':'None'},{'valuej':None},{'value':None}],'KEYE':[{'valuez':None, 'check':'no'},{'valueeeee':None},{'valuecde':None}]}
```